Dependency mismatching in requirement file in AWS Manager Workflows for Apache Airflow(MWAA)
I was trying to upgrade the version of Apache Airflow from 2.2.2 to 2.10.2 but I was getting the error with installing the packages in the requirement.txt file in dbt-redshift , dbt-postgres , dbt-core . The versions of dbt-postgres , dbt-core are working as of now but dbt-redshift is causing the problem at a specific version . I don't have the exact logs(one of the dependency was redshift-connector) but if we went higher it was clashing with another package and if we went lower it was clashing with different package. If someone can please tell the versions of dbt-redshift , dbt-postgres , dbt-core for any of the following versions of MWAA - 2.7 , 2.8 , 2.9 , 2.10 so that other dependencies don't clash.
The requirement file is as follows :
---constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.2.2/constraints-3.7.txt"
dbt-core==1.2.3
dbt-postgres==1.2.3
dbt-redshift==1.2.1
apache-airflow-providers-ssh
apache-airflow-providers-sftp
apache-airflow-providers-amazon
loguru==0.6.0
pysftp==0.2.9
paramiko==2.8.0
pycryptodome==3.11.0
pydantic
cryptography==3.4.8
bcrypt==3.2.0
pandas==1.3.4

I tried multiple versions of these packages but nothing worked.
